# Distinguish between latency-sensitive and batch-processing processes at kernel level

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, real-time, batch-processing

I'm looking for a reliable way to distinguish between batch-processing processes (e.g. garbage collectors) and latency-sensitive processes (e.g. key-value stores such as Redis) at the kernel level.

I was thinking of using hardware performance counters but I need to know the behavioral difference between these two types at the PMU counters level.

Is there any reliable way to achieve this at the kernel level? Considering all are running on the CFS scheduler.

Comment: check their niceness

Comment: All have niceness of 0 by default. @stark

Comment: then they all have equal priority as far as the scheduler is concerned.

Comment: Exactly! But they are not the same inherently. Imagine wanting to set the niceness dynamically. My concern is how to distinguish between them in any way?!

Comment: Is there any difference other than niceness? @stark

Answer (score 1):

You should probably check the load of the threads, as computed by CFS. The load corresponds to how much time a thread was runnable (not running, just able to run) relative to the time it was allocated by CFS. Batch processing processes would tend to have a high load as they use all the CPU time they can, while latency-sensitive tasks would tend to have a lower load as they usually frequently block/unblock.

Note that this is not 100% accurate, and some latency-sensitive applications may have threads using all their CPU time, therefore having a high load. But the load might be a good first approximation that does not necessitate using hardware counters and implementing complicated stuff.

You can read this great article about how CFS tracks the load of threads: https://lwn.net/Articles/531853/

Comment: Thanks. This is a good hint to look at indeed.

Comment: BTW, I'm okay with implementation if you have a more reliable solution in mind that needs implementation.

Comment: I was not thinking about anything in particular. I just assumed that most things you would implement for your purpose might be complicated, at least more than just using the load.